# How to insure there always is a at-least interval time between every invocation of a method in Java?

Tags: java

If there is a method called `DontCallMeContinuously`:

```
public void DontCallMeContinuously {
  //...
}
```

the minimum interval I set is 2000ms.

What I want to see is that **when I call this method twice with interval time less than 2000ms, the second call have to wait for some time until the interval time is greater than 2000ms**.

How could this be done in Java? Is there any decent way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are two options for you.
(a) return the method if the call is too frequent.
(b) wait the current invocation and execute the method

```
static long lastInvocation;
static long interval = 2000; // 2seconds
public void DontCallMeContinuously {
    long current = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastInvocation ==null)
        lastInvocation = current;
    else if((current - lastInvocation)<interval)
        return; // change this to sleep(current-lastinvocation) if you want to do (b)
    lastInvocation = current;
    // execute the method.
}
```

lastInvocation is the time in mills when the method was called last time. If is the first time, set the lastInvocation as current time. Else find the diff between current and last and compare with the interval.

Comment: Quote from OP: The second call have to wait for some time until the interval time is greater than 2000ms.

Comment: @Aerus : I have edited the answer. There can be scenarios where its better to return the method and prompt the user to try after some time.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final long MIN_INTERVAL = 2000;
private volatile long lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();

public void DontCallMeContinuously() {
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCall;

    if (elapsed < MIN_INTERVAL) {
        assert !SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() : "don't sleep on the EDT!";

        long wait = MIN_INTERVAL - elapsed;
        lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    } else {
        lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    // method body
}
```

This will do it. Don't do something like this unless you know the thread is safe to sleep on. For example don't ever call this method inside a Swing event, it will freeze the GUI. If you plan on doing this on the EDT you might want to make a special case for that.

An alternative that is relatively Swing-safe is to use a javax.swing.Timer:

```
public void DontCallMeContinuously() {
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCall;

    if (elapsed < MIN_INTERVAL) {
        synchronized (this) {
            long wait = MIN_INTERVAL - lastCall;
            lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait;
        }

        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {

            Timer delay = new Timer(wait, new ActionListener() {
                @Override public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DontCallMeContinouslyBody();
                }
            }
            delay.setRepeats(false);
            delay.start();

        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            DontCallMeContinouslyBody();
        }
    }
}

private void DontCallMeContinouslyBody() {
    // real method body
}
```

Also notice that my example sets the last call time as a time *in the future*. This allows for a simple queuing mechanism if the method is accessed by multiple threads.